# jQuery Ajax Accessing json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have been trying to access certain part of the json response, however I am unable to do so.

```
json = '{

"now": "2010-09-23 22:06:53 EST",

"data":[

{"id":"1","year":"2010","month":"09","day":"23","hours":"08","minutes":"09","seconds":"25"},{"id":"8","year":"2010","month":"09","day":"23","hours":"08","minutes":"09","seconds":"18"},    {"id":"3","year":"2010","month":"09","day":"23","hours":"08","minutes":"09","seconds":"24"},{"id":"4","year":"2010","month":"09","day":"23","hours":"08","minutes":"09","seconds":"30"}]}';
```

I am parsing my data using this:

```
var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
alert(resp.data);
```

How can I access month of id 3 for instance?

Thanks

I have tried alert(resp.data[0]) but no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$.each(resp.data,function(i,v){
    if(v.id == 3) {
        alert(v.month) // alerts "09"
    }
});
```

Comment: @RPM1984 the OP want it to get the month based on `id`.

Comment: Ah true, he did. Didnt read that properly, my bad. lucky i didnt answer :)

Comment: @RPM1984 thanks anyways, I was also looking for your that kind of answer.